# Delete rows and insert rows in Ranges declared as Variant

Tags: excel, vba

I have to go through the complete A column and check if cell value length is < 6 then delete it.

I used to perform the operations on the sheet like this

```
 activesheet.range("A" & row_number).select
 selection.entirerow.delete
```

As people suggested using a variant I want to work with variants.

I have taken a set of range into a variant.

```
 dim var as variant 
 var=sheet1.range("A1:D1000").value
```

Suppose I have 20 rows whose cell value length in A column is less than 6. I have to remove these 20 rows in the variant variable, including the other corresponding columns in variant that is B, C, D. I mean var("A18:D18") should be completely removed.

I heard people say we can't delete an entry from a variant, we should take a new variant and copy only those values into the new variant. If that is the situation how do I copy one variant to another variant?

For rows whose A column cell value length is greater than 6, cell values should be converted into a standard format. I have done it using the sheet like

```
activesheet.cells("some cell!).value=activesheet.cells("").value
```

I loop through each row and it is taking some time as every time I'm knocking the sheet for values. I want to use variants now, take the complete range, perform the operation and write it back.

How to remove the complete row that we entered into variant like var("A2:D2"), then copy the var("A4:D4") value to other variant like var2("A6:D6")?

Can we also insert an entry into variant at the middle of the variant like we insert row in the sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

1. It takes A1:D1000 on the first worksheet (array X)
2. Tests each column  A cell to see if it is longer than 6 characters
3. If it is greater than 6 then the entire row (4 cells in your case) is written as a
   new row in array Y
4. The reduced array is written to A1 in the sexcond worksheet
5. Added formatting of sheet1 columns to sheet2 columns

   ```
   Sub VarExample()
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet
   Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
   Dim X
   Dim Y
   Dim lngRow As Long
   Dim lngCOl As Long
   Dim lngCnt As Long
   'define the size of the array to be processed on sheet 1
   X = ws1.Range("A1:D1000").Value2
   'make the second array the same size as the first
   ReDim Y(1 To UBound(X, 1), 1 To UBound(X, 2))
   'Look at the first record in each row  [,1] part to see if it is longer than 6 chars
   For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
       If Len(X(lngRow, 1)) > 6 Then
        'Longer than 6 so add 1 more row to the length of the 2nd array
           lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
           'Loop through value in this row of the first array and place in the second array
           For lngCOl = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
               Y(lngCnt, lngCOl) = X(lngRow, lngCOl)
           Next lngCOl
       End If
   Next
   'create a range on the second sheet equal in size to the second array and dump the array to it
   ws1.[a1].Resize(UBound(Y, 1), UBound(Y, 2)).Value2 = Y
   'copy formatting
   ws1.[a1].Resize(1, UBound(X, 2)).EntireColumn.Copy
   ws2.[a1].Resize(1, UBound(X, 2)).EntireColumn.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: comments added niko as requested, pls let me know if you have any further queries. cheers